# How to write R function that can take either a vector or formula as first argument?

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a function that I want to be able to take both a vector and a formula as a first argument. If it is a vector, I do some single variable calculations, if it is a formula, I analyze the first variable by the second variable (the second variable would always be a factor).

Here is my current code:

```
fun = function(formula,data) {

  if (class(with(data,formula))=="formula") {
    mod = model.frame(formula,data)
    n.group=names(mod)[2] 
    group <- eval(parse(text=paste("mod$",n.group,sep=""))) #x
    response <- model.response(mod) # y
    return(table(response,group))
  }

  else {
    return(table(with(data,formula)))
  }
}

data(iris)

fun(Sepal.Length~Species,iris) # works correctly
fun(Sepal.Length,iris) # returns an error
```

The return value is just for illustration.

Cheers!

Comment: `with(fun(Sepal.Length, iris))`, "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Sepal.Length' not found" should have been a good indication of the error.

Comment: sorry, `with(iris, fun(Sepal.Length, iris))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fun.formula <- function(formula, data) {
  mod = model.frame(formula, data)
  n.group <- names(mod)[2] 
  group <- eval(parse(text=paste("mod$",n.group,sep=""))) #x
  response <- model.response(mod) # y
  table(response, group)
}

fun <- function(formula, data) {
    ret <- try( table(eval(substitute(formula), data), silent = TRUE)
    if (inherits(try, "try-error)) fun.formula(formula, data) else ret
}

# tests
fun(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris)
fun(Sepal.Length, iris)
```

That said, this is a rather unusual interface and, instead, it might be better to specify the case where formula is a variable by passing its name as a character string in which case a more usual S3 implementation is possible:

```
fun2 <- function(formula, data, ...) UseMethod("fun2")
fun2.formula <- fun.formula
fun2.character <- function(formula, data) table(data[[formula]])

# tests
fun2(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris)
fun2("Sepal.Length", iris) # with this approach use a character string
```

**REVISED** Now we use `try` and added an S3 approach.

Comment: Thank you for your response - it pushed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I would have solved this using an S3 approach, but I couldn't figure out how to do that. The following got the job done:

```
fun <- function(x,data) {
  mod = try(model.frame(x,data),silent=T)
  if (inherits(mod, "try-error")) {
    x=data[,deparse(substitute(x))]
    return(table(x))
  }
  else {
    mod = model.frame(x,data)
    n.group=names(mod)[2] 
    group <- eval(parse(text=paste("mod$",n.group,sep=""))) #x
    response <- model.response(mod) # y
    return(table(response,group))    
  }
}

fun(Sepal.Length~Species,iris) # works correctly
fun(Sepal.Length,iris) # works!
```